# How to use paging library with groupe library for recyclerView and where to put filter statements?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

**
Hello, I am using kotlin MVVM pattern and I want to use groupe library for interacting with recyclerView.
My question is : How to use paging library with this groupe library and where should I put the filter statements to filter the recyclerView?
I am not so expert so I want some help for this please.
**

```
import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.Item
import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.ViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.song.*

class SongItem(private val song: Song) : Item() {

    override fun getLayout() = R.layout.song

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.title.text = song.title
        viewHolder.title.artist = song.artist
    }
}
```